# "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have a problem in my GET route. As the title says.
Html code:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let room of rooms">
```

Component:

```
rooms : any;
this.rooms = this.roomsService.getRooms();
```

Provider:

```
  getRooms(){
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/rooms/')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
    });
});
```

}

And server side:

```
exports.getRooms = function (req, res) {
Room.find({}, function (err, rooms) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    } else {
        res.json(rooms);
    }
});
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Structure of returning json:

```
[ { _id: 58eb65dcfd9b3c188c74d811,
room_number: 1,
type: 'standard',
beds: 1,
max_occupancy: 1,
cost_per_night: 50,
__v: 0,
reserved: [] },
{ _id: 58eb6608fd9b3c188c74d812,
room_number: 2,
type: 'standard',
beds: 1,
max_occupancy: 1,
cost_per_night: 55,
__v: 0,
reserved: [] } ]
```

Comment: what is the structure of the returned data ?

Comment: Share the json structure

Comment: added in first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this in quite a simple way. There was something wrong with:

```
this.rooms = this.roomsService.getRooms();
```

Because I couldnt assign promise like this directly, so I did:

```
this.roomsService.getRooms().then((data) => {
    this.rooms = data;
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```